# How do I move a VM to a different Geographic Region Azure

Tags: azure

I created a VM in US West and I want to move it to East Asia.

I Read this MS documentation and found out that the move from US West to East ASia is not supported based on geographic region.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-tutorial-migrate?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-machines%2flinux%2ftoc.json

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you may want to copy the Azure VM to a different region. The main thought is to create a new VM in the new region from a Disk Snapshots based on the source Azure VM. There are many ways to do this. You could follow [this1](https://www.obungi.com/2017/07/21/how-to-copy-an-azure-vm-from-region-a-to-region-b/) or [this2](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/06/09/the-quickest-way-to-create-new-vms-in-azure-from-existing-vm-snapshots-mostly-with-powershell/).

[image]